# Stuck with deploying django with apache + mod_wsgi

Tags: django, deployment, apache2, mod-wsgi, error-log

I get an 500 internal server error and in the log files it writes:

```
[Thu Jun 14 16:30:22 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] ImportError: Could not import settings 'mysite.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named mysite.settings
```

here is my httpd.conf:

```
ServerName localhost

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin ttt@mysite.com
    ServerName mysite.com
    ServerAlias www.mysite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite/
    LogLevel warn
    WSGIDaemonProcess processes=2 maximum-requests=500 threads=1
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py
    Alias /media /var/www/mysite/mysite/static/media/
</VirtualHost>
```

wsgi.py:

```
import os

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: You are missing WSGIProcessGroup. Your application would not be delegated to the daemon process group with what you have.

Comment: nope that's not the problem... my sys path was the problem

Comment: The sys.path may well have been your problem, but you are still missing a WSGIProcessGroup directive. See http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/CheckingYourInstallation#Embedded_Or_Daemon_Mode

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This problem is covered in both the mod-wsgi documentation http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/IntegrationWithDjango and the Django deployment documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/ which note that the project must be on your Python path. You can use the `WSGIPythonPath` directive or set the `python-path` in your `WSGIDaemonProcess` directive from the Django documentation. Or you can add it to the `sys.path` in your wsgi file as the mod-wsgi docs state.

Comment: I get this error:WSGIPythonPath cannot occur within <VirtualHost> section

Comment: My mistake. I've updated the answer to reflect that you can set the path in your `WSGIDaemonProcess`.

Comment: ie: import sys # virtual environment paths
site.addsitedir('/home/<sitehome>/virtualenv/.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/')